# How to hide XHR requests from network tab in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, angular, xmlhttprequest

I am getting data from my mongoDB using nodejs server and displaying it on my react home page.
The issue is all my data has been showing into the network tab of google chrome devtools. I just don't wanna let users to read all these data.

Is this possible? How?  OR Is there any other way to do same things?

Please tell me how to hide data from network.

Here is the screenshots :

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5d0y.png)

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gOWY.png)

Comment: If you don’t want users to read it, don’t sent it to the browser..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways to "hide" them or actually make them less obvious to find;

Make a JSONP request, they are not real AJAX calls, as they do not use the XMLHttpRequest object. They simply inject a script tag in the dom, the requests are still visible in the network tab.

You can also clear console via script among the lines of

```
function clearConsole() { 
    if(window.console || window.console.firebug) {
       console.clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately for you, there's no way to hide network requests from Chrome Network Log.

Even if you could, it'd be still possible to use network analyzer tools such as Fiddler and Wireshark to log all the traffic between your computer and the Internet.